# Join Three Tables And Group By One Field With COUNT function

Tags: sql, join, group-by

I have three tables - Sections, Themes and Comments.

Simple View:

### Sections

-SectionId

### Themes

-ThemeId
-SectionId

### Comments

-CommentId
-ThemeId

And I need to write sql query to get the result like this:

-SectionId
-CountOfThemes
-CountOfComments

### Resolved:

```
Select 
    Section.SectionId As SessionId, 
    Section.SectionTitle As SessionTitle,
    Count(Distinct Theme.ThemeId) As CountTheme,
    Count(Distinct Comment.CommentId) As CountComment

From Section
Left Join Theme On Section.SectionId = Theme.SectionId
LEFT JOIN Comment ON Theme.ThemeId = Comment.ThemeId
Group By 
    Section.SectionId,
    Section.SectionTitle
```

Comment: try count(distinct theme.themeID)

Answer (score 1):

Try using COUNT(DISTINCT Theme.ThemeId) and COUNT(DISTINCT Comment.CommentId)

I think your issue is that you have a one to many relationship between themes and comments, and therefore you are getting duplicate ThemeIds counted where there is more than one comment.

Also your code: `left Join Comment On Comment.ThemeId = Theme.ThemeId`

I would consider changing to `LEFT JOIN Comment ON Theme.ThemeId = Comment.ThemeId`